# Remove temp variable in code with switch-block

Tags: variables, return, switch-statement, break, temporary

Have such code in project:

```
Cookie CookieCreate(CookiesTypes type)
{
     Cookie user_cookie = null;

     switch (type)
     {
             case CookiesTypes.SessionId:
                  user_cookie = new Cookie("session_id", Convert.ToBase64String(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray()));
                  break;
             case CookiesTypes.ClientIp:
                  HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
                  user_cookie = new Cookie("client_ip", context.Request.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
                  break;
     }

     return user_cookie;
}
```

I understand, that temp variable `user_cookie` is bad syntax... I've tried to use `return` in switch-block both in two cases, but I've got an compiler erros, when I tried so:

Pseudo-Code:

```
case ... :
     //some action
    return var;
```

Comment: Why do you think using a local-scope variable is a bad syntax? It makes a coder more clear and code flow complete.

Answer (score 1):

Having a temporary that is set in a case of a `switch` statement to be returned at the end is not a bad syntax, it is also the only choice if you need to do something on `user_cookie` for all cases before returning it.

The only problem is see in your code is the lack of a `default` case which is indeed useful because:

- either you can require a `default` case (so that you do something in that situation)
- either the switch should never reach a `default` case (so you should manage that situation in a special way, for example by throwing an exception)

If you blindly remove temporary variable and return the value directly like you are trying to do, then it gives you a compiler error probably because not all your branches do return something (because you are lacking a `default` clause or lacking a `return` after the switch).

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that *there's nothing inherently wrong* with temporary variables, if you really want to avoid it you just need to ensure that all code paths return something.

That means (for example) changing your current `return` to:

```
return null;
```

and having both cases contain:

```
return new Cookie (whatever);
```

instead of the assignment.